# CVS Checkout issue

Tags: cvs, aptana3

Hi I am using aptana studio 3.

When i am trying to checkout the code from cvs i am getting the following error messages.

( i have checked the permission in my local folders. they are not restricted. and i am using windows 7 operation system)

cvs checkout: Updating BOOKING_2012
    cvs checkout: failed to create lock directory for `/export/home/booking/APP' (/export/home/booking/APP/#cvs.lock): Permission denied
    cvs checkout: failed to obtain dir lock in repository`/export/home/booking/APP'
    cvs [checkout aborted]: read lock failed - giving up
The server reported an error while performing the "cvs checkout" command. (took 30:00.707)
   Error: : cvs checkout: failed to create lock directory for `/export/home/booking/APP' (/export/home/booking/APP/#cvs.lock): Permission denied
   Error: : cvs checkout: failed to obtain dir lock in repository`/export/home/booking/APP'
   Error: : cvs [checkout aborted]: read lock failed - giving up

Thanks in advance,
Shanker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lock file is being created in `/var/lock/cvs/foo/` --- you should check the permissions of that directory.